react-select change option background color on click
This is what my dropdown looks like normally:

and when I hold click on it it changes to:

option: (baseStyles, state) => ({
        ...baseStyles,
        backgroundColor: state.isFocused ? '#3b383c' : 'black',
    })

How do I prevent this color change from happening? I couldn't find what the key for the click state was in the docs.
